# Creating a name/email-textfile from the output of ldapsearch

Tags: regex, awk, ldap, grep

well, I need to generate a single text file with name and emailaddress in the format

name, emailaddress

from the output of ldapsearch. But that is not as simple as it looks like (at least for me).

I am at the point where I have a list of email addresses:

```
 ldapsearch -x -b ou=<somevalue>,ou=<somevalue>,ou=<somevalue>,dc=<somevalue>,dc=<somevalue> objectClass=posixAccount | grep "^mail: .*$" | awk '{print $2}'
```

and a list of names:

```
 ldapsearch -x -b ou=<somevalue>,ou=<somevalue>,ou=<somevalue>,dc=<somevalue>,dc=<somevalue> objectClass=posixAccount | grep "^description: .*$" | awk '{print $2,$3}'
```

but whatever I tried - I don't get one single command giving me the list I need as shown above ...

This command gives me both name and email - but not in one line:

```
ldapsearch -x -b ou=<somevalue>,ou=<somevalue>,ou=<somevalue>,dc=<somevalue>,dc=<somevalue> objectClass=posixAccount | awk '/description:|mail:/{print $2,$3}'
```

Is there a way to make a cool regex to solve this?
Or something brilliant shell command I would not think of?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

regards

Dirk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall, this ldap output records separated by blank lines, so you could write:

```
perl -00 -ne '
    /(?<=description: )(.*$)/m and print "$1, ";
    /(?<=mail: )(.*$)/m and print "$1\n";
'
```

Comment: Great, this works ! Many thanks for your answer, the command now does what it has to do - a list with names and emailadresses :-) This saves me much time, thanks again :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem you have is that the output of `ldapsearch` spools on to separate lines, so when you `grep`, you get something like:

```
description: Joe Bloggs
mail: jbloggs@example.com
```

If you can assume that all your directory entries have a `description` and `mail` field and that `ldapsearch` will consistently output them in this order, then you can pipe the result of `grep` into `sed` (here shown on multiple lines for clarity):

```
ldapsearch ... |
grep -e '^(description|mail):' |
sed -e 'N;s/description: \(.*\)\nmail: \(.*\)/\1, \2/;P;D'
```

This `sed` script groups lines into two, then runs a regex substitute (note that this isn't necessarily portable, so you might need to experiment) to remove the field names, prints and deletes its current buffer, so it can move to the next pair. You may be able to produce a magic regex that doesn't care about the order in which fields are returned by `ldapsearch`, but life's too short!

Comment: Nice. One comment on the sed script, you do not need to explicitly print-delete, that will happen automatically, i.e. you can drop the `P;D` bit.

Comment: I don't know exactly why, but my system gives results for ...| grep -e '^description:' and it gives results for ...| grep -e '^mail:' - but no result for ...| grep -e '^(description|mail):' each try without the sed command, just the grep...

Comment: Anyway I gave the second answer a try and it works for me - thank you for your answer, I am sure it works generally, but unfortunately my system seems to be incompatible to this solution.

Comment: You may need to escape the matching parentheses: `grep -e '^\(description|mail\):'`